# java generics <? extends A> v.s <A> vs <? super A>

Tags: java, generics

This could be a very stupid question, however I don't understand why the compiler complains and compiles.

I have two very simple classes:

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Now the codes:

```
//block1
List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new A()); //ok
list.add(new B()); //ok 

//block2
List<? extends A> extendList= new ArrayList<>();
extendList.add(new A()); //not ok, why?
extendList.add(new B()); //not ok, why?

//block3
List<? super A> superList = new ArrayList<>();
superList.add(new A()); //ok
superList.add(new B()); //ok. why?
```

The block1 I know why it worked.

The block2, I have `<? extends A>`, as I understood, the list is gonna accept objects with type `A` or subType of `A`, for example `B`. Why both `add()` lines failed? with error:

```
Error: no suitable method found for add(A)
method java.util.Collection.add(capture#1 of ? extends A) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; A cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends A)
method java.util.List.add(capture#1 of ? extends A) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; A cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends A)
```

The block3, I have `<? super A>`, as I understood, the list is gonna accept objects with type `A` or superType of `A`, `B` is a **subType** of `A`, why `add(new B())` compiles?

I think I could have misunderstanding of the `super` and `extends` keywords, I did some google, however my doubt is still there.

A sentence from oracle generic tutorial: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

```
The term List<Number> is more restrictive than List<? extends Number>
because the former matches a list of type Number only, whereas the 
latter matches a list of type Number or any of its subclasses.
```

Comment: I have a guess, but could you try doing `List<? extends A> extendList= new ArrayList<A>();` ? I don't think the `<>` knows how to infer from <? extends A>, whereas <? super A> is saying "any subclass of A"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

block2: *"as I understood, the list is gonna accept objects with type A or subType of A, for example B"* - no!  Think about the possible values of `?`, e.g. it could be a `class C extends A { }` and that would mean that neither `A` nor `B` match the constraint. You cannot add `A` or `B` into a list with generic type `C`.

block3: once again think about the possible values of `?`: right now it can be `A` or any of its super classes, so `A` or `Object` (or anything in between). Since `B` is a subtype of `A` it is of course a sub type of all the super classes of `A` as well. Every `List` that accepts an `A` will accept a `B` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scenario to make it clear. Consider a third class:

```
class C extends A {
}

List<C> cList = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends A> extendList = cList; //this is valid. Right? Yes
```

With that, the reason for the failure becomes clear. If `extendList.add(new A())` were allowed, the following would also have to be legal:

```
extendList.add(new B());
```

But then we would be adding an **incompatible** type (`B`) to the list (of `C`)

The reason is the boundary: `<? super A>` is guaranteed to be compatible with any subtype of `A`. However, `<? extends B>` allows subtypes of `A` that could be incompatible with one another.

Answer (score 0):

`List<? extends A> extendList= new ArrayList<>();
extendList.add(new A()); //not ok, why?
extendList.add(new B()); //not ok, why?`

Imagine that your `A` is `Animal`. Now you have a `List<? extends Animal>`, so you have a list of something that is an animal, it can be a list of `Dog`, `Cat`, or even `Animal`, but you don't know which one. You are trying to insert something into it (impossible by the way), and you can't do it, because like I said, you don't know what is in the list. It could be `List<Cat>` and you are trying to insert a `Dog` into it. You can't even insert `Animal` - because `Animal` could be a `Dog`, who knows.

You can `get` from that list tho, because you know that whatever you pick from that list can be assigned to `Animal`, so no problems there. Notice that in block 3 you can't get anything from the list, but you can insert - it's the other way around.

You can insert into `List<? super Animal>`, because you know that whatever is in there is an Animal or higher. So you can insert `Dog`, `Cat` or `Animal`, because they are all animals. Notice that you can't get anything from that list. It's a list of things that are supertype of `Animal`, list of `LivingBeing` for example (Animal, Human etc.). What would you assign it to? `Human human = list.get(0)` - what if that particular object is not a Human but an Animal? `LivingBeing livingBeing = list.get(0)` - what if it's not a list of livingBeings, but something higher or simply different than that, but still a supertype of `Animal`?

Have a look at [Effective Java 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997) and [Koltin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) - yes, Kotlin, it has a slightly different approach to this which can help you understand it more. Kotlin language has put all of that into clean rules.